# How to turn a hclust-object into JSON for D3?

Tags: json, r, d3.js, dendrogram, hclust

I'm attempting to visualize a cluster tree using [this awesome D3 layout](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html)! However, it needs data in JSON format - how do I go from a `hclust-object` in R to a hierarchical JSON structure?

```
set.seed(123)
m <- matrix(runif(100), nrow=10)
cl <- hclust(dist(m))
plot(cl)
```

My googling turned up this [hclustToTree](https://github.com/jcheng5/d3-heatmap/blob/master/hclust.R) function which returns a list that looks promising - but I don't really know where to go from there. Any advice would be much appreciated.

```
halfway <- hclustToTree(cl)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there:

```
jsonTree <- toJSON(halfway)  # part of the RJSONIO library
```

Comment: Looking at the D3 JSON here: https://bitbucket.org/john2x/d3test/src/2ce4dd511244/d3/examples/data/flare.json You will.

The `"name"` field will be correctly be filled out if the rows of your original matrix are named.  Try `rownames(m) <- letters[1:10]`.